# Are deleted answers appear greyed out?

Tags: support

I sometime see Q/A topics where an answer is greyed out.

eg (look at the -4 answer) : [Why multiple PTR records in DNS is not recommended?](https://serverfault.com/questions/618700/why-multiple-ptr-records-in-dns-is-not-recommended)

Could you say what it means ?

I believe these are deleted answers, but absolutely not sure...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gray text only means that the answer is voted -3 or lower.

You do not see deleted posts at all (until you reach 10,000 reputation, or if they are your own); those appear with [a pink background](https://serverfault.com/a/690728/126632).

Comment: Thank you @Michael Hampton

Comment: lol ! I love the link you reference to :) ;) Will review my RFC reading skills, i promise ;)

Comment: <grin> OK, good, thanks!